# Pandas groupby 2 coluns/conditions then value_counts() by another column?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, data-analysis

Here's what the dataset I'm working on looks like:

| Type | SubType | Municipality |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Social Media | Facebook | New Castle |
| Onground | Campus | Monroe |
| Onground | Cafe | Kutlski |
| Social Media | Instagram | New Castle |
| Social Media | Tiktok | San Andreas |
| Social Media | Facebook | New Castle |
| Social Media | Facebook | San Andreas |

I want to group it by **Type** and **SubType** then further filter it by **Municipality** and then `value_counts()` it.

Here's what I've tried:

```
ab = df.groupby([df['Type'] == 'Social Media', 
                     df['SubType']])
ab['Municipality'].value_counts()
```

I almost got what I want only that it shows everything, not just the result of the condition (under the Type column, it has 'true' and false' section.

This is the result I'm looking for:

| Type | SubType | Municipality |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Social Media | Facebook | New Castle | 2 |
|  |  | San Andreas | 1 |
|  | Instagram | New castle | 1 |
|  | TikTok | San Andreas | 1 |

But instead, this is my result:

| Type | SubType | Municipality |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| True | Facebook | New Castle | 2 |
|  |  | San Andreas | 1 |
|  | Instagram | New Castle | 1 |
|  | Titkok | San Andreas | 1 |
| False | Onground | Cafe | 1 |
|  |  | Campus | 1 |
| and so on... | .... | .... | ... |

Answer (score 0):

Just filter first and group only by subtype. `` df.query('Type == `Social Media`').groupby('SubType')['Municipality'].value_counts() ``

Comment: Of course! what am I thinking!? Lol. Thank you! :)

Comment: why not simply `df.query("Type == 'Social Media'").value_counts()`  or `df.query("Type == 'Social Media'")[["Type","SubType","Municipality"]].value_counts()` if DF contains also another columns ? ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think value_counts is what you are looking for

```
df.value_counts(['Type','SubType','Municipality'])
Out[169]: 
Type          SubType    Municipality
Social Media  Facebook   New Castle      2
Onground      Cafe       Kutlski         1
              Campus     Monroe          1
Social Media  Facebook   San Andreas     1
              Instagram  New Castle      1
```